# How to Change Color of Symbols in Legend for Two-Way Lowess

Tags: stata

I'm trying to change the color of the two lines in the legend for a two-way lowess plot.

My code is as follows:

```
twoway (lowess y x if z == 0) (lowess y x if z == 1), ///  
        title("Probabilistic Relationship between Incidence of Y and Diagnosis of X") ///  
        ytitle(Probability of Incidence of Y)                  ///  
        ylabel(0.0 0.05 0.10 0.15 0.20)                            ///  
        xtitle(Diagnosis of X)                      ///  
        legend(label(1 "Non-Z") label(2 "Current Z")) ///  
        rline(lcolor(1 "eltblue") (2 "eltgreen"),                       ///  
        lstyle(1 "solid") (2 "solid"))                          ///  
        note("Anonymous Project")
```

I keep getting errors on various lines of code, particular for rline and lstyle. What options am I supposed to use for twoway lowess to edit the color of the lines in the plot and correspondingly, the legend? The lcolor and rline options don't work. Please guide me on how to navigate this issue!

Comment: Off-topic here, but try  `tw (lowess price mpg if foreign==1, lcolor(orange)) (lowess price mpg if foreign==0, lcolor(navy)), legend(label(1 "Foreign Cars") label(2 "Domestic Cars")) ` on the cars dataset. I found that [this book](https://www.crcpress.com/A-Visual-Guide-to-Stata-Graphics-Third-Edition/Mitchell/p/book/9781597181068) is a good intro to Stata graphics. Reading that makes the documentation a lot more understandable.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Unfortunately, lcolor does not work as the command doesn't consider this a line plot.

Comment: I have no idea what "does not work" means here. I don't have your data, I don't know exactly what you typed. Hard to help without a reproducible example showing the code.

Comment: My x and y variables are dichotomous, not continuous so I don't know how the same method would work. I simply edited it using graph editor, but thank you for your help!

Comment: With a dichotomous outcome you can use the `adjust` option in lowess. But with a dichotomous x, lowess does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example:

```
sysuse auto
tw (lowess price mpg if foreign==1, lcolor(orange)) (lowess price mpg if foreign==0, lcolor(navy)), legend(label(1 "Foreign Cars") label(2 "Domestic Cars"))
```

Here's the output:

[image]